# Voice Command to Select TableView Options

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, voice

It's something which I've heard for the first time in iOS. I'm making an app where when user taps on a `TabBar` button it opens a popup menu with some options in a `TableView`. Now the client wants user to speak and select an option from the list.
For example if the list contains Open Camera, Open Photos and user say Open Camera it should open camera. So, my question is that is it possible? If so than I need any tutorial or related links. So far I've searched for it but found nothing so I must be doing the wrong search.

Comment: I am not sure but this http://www.politepix.com/openears/ might be helpful for you.

Comment: The content of rows of table is fixed or they will be dynamic ?

Comment: @BadalShah is right, if your content is fixed then (http://www.politepix.com/openears/tutorial/) is the best option.

Comment: @Hima thanks for tutorial link..

Comment: You are welcome, see details in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps to work with open ears for offline speech  recognition.

1. On Offline speech recognition tutorial.
   [image]
2. Find `Using OELanguageModelGenerator` steps.  Here you need to
   define your own words which you want to use (i.e. here, you need to
   set your UITableview row's title)[image]

These was the main steps you need to know, after registering , you will get your API key and by following rest of the instructions you will be able to achieve what you want.